# Galaxy Nexus - How do I start adding strangers' numbers to "auto-reject"?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, call-screening

I regularly get phone calls from people trying to reach an old folks' home and I want to outright reject those automatically (without any "send to voicemail" ideally).

This was fairly painless on the Galaxy S: from the Call Log, tap-hold on the bad number, menu pops up, select "add to auto-reject". [Auto reject was enabled in the phone's settings before]

How do I achieve the same thing with the Galaxy Nexus?  I'm figuring the same feature should be available from the stock ICS somewhere.  If not, I'm open to lists of auto-reject apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the same people ringing you regularly what you could do is:

- Add them as a contact, under 'Ignore1', 'Ignore2' etc. whenever they
  ring
- Go to Contacts -> Select 'Ignore1' -> Options (or action menu) -> Select 'All calls to voicemail'

Or if you don't like this method then you could try:

- [Mr. Number: Text, Call & Block](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrnumber.blocker)
  (free)
- [Extreme Call Blocker Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greythinker.punchback)  (paid)

Comment: I didn't want to add a new contact called "Auto Reject List", but I guess it's good enough for now... Although, I'm just going to add all of the rejects into the same contact, because it's cleaner than flooding my contact list with "Ignore #1, #2, #3... etc"

Comment: Ah yes I didn't think of adding them to the same one. I know it's irritating have to have them saved as a contact, you'd think you could just block people and then have a separate list of who you've blocked so you can revoke it if you change your mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Call Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=call.manager).